# Declaring a variable in an if statement, a Python anti pattern?

Tags: python, anti-patterns

We discussed in my job about the following piece of Python code (maybe an anti-pattern):

```
if conditional_variable_:
    a = "Some value"
print a
```

Supose `conditional_variable` was defined but `a` variable didn't.

The question is about using a variable without declaring it. The variable `a` is created inside a piece of code that maybe never will be executed but it is used.

Maybe that fix may repair the anti-pattern:

```
a = "default value"
if conditional_variable:
    a = "changed_value"
print a
```

In that case, `a` variable was defined before use it. Consider `print a` like a ussage of the `a` variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not an anti-pattern. It is a *bug*.

Python has no 'declarations', only [binding operations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding); a name is either bound, or it is not. Trying to access a name that hasn't been bound to yet results in an exception.

Unless your code specifically handles the exception and *expected it*, running into a `NameError` or `UnboundLocalError` exception should be considered a bug.

In other words, code that tries to reference a name should always be subject to the same conditions that bind the name, *or* be prepared to handle the exception that'll be raised if those conditions don't always hold. Giving your variable a default value outside the `if` statement means it is bound under *all* circumstances, so you can also reference it always.